# Efficiently iterating though a large corpus (python)

Tags: python

```
def getPairsWithMaximumPMI(self, words, N):
    print("\nSubtask 3: given a list of words, find the pairs with the greatest PMI")
    #return [(1.0, "foo", "bar")]

    possiblePairs = list(combinations(words, 2))
    currMaxPMI = 0.0
    res = [[]]

    print("Total pairs", (len(possiblePairs)))

    for p in possiblePairs:
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
        if(self.getPMI(p[0], p[1]) > currMaxPMI):
            currMaxPMI = self.getPMI(p[0], p[1])
            res[0] = (currMaxPMI, p[0], p[1])

    print(res)
    return res
```

My function basically creates all possible pairs of words from a given 'words' list and stores in possiblePairs .

```
e.g. ['I', 'am', 'you'] --> [('I','am'), ('I', 'you'), ('am','you')]
```

Then iterates through this possiblePairs and do some computation that is not important in my question.

The thing is, when the possiblePairs is huge, it takes about 30 minutes to do the computation and this is not what I desire.

What do I have to do to make algorithm more efficient?

I am new to this kind of stuff, so I need help.

Edit:

```
    currMaxPMI = 0.0
    res = [[]]
    counter = 0
    #print("Total pairs", (len(possiblePairs)))

    for p in (combinations(words, 2)):

        counter += 1
        print(counter)
        if(self.getPMI(p[0], p[1]) > currMaxPMI):
            currMaxPMI = self.getPMI(p[0], p[1])
            res[0] = (currMaxPMI, p[0], p[1])

    print(res)
    return res
```

Comment: You can do `import itertools; itertools.product(list1, list2, etc)`

Comment: @HyperNeutrino could you please elaborate?

Comment: The `itertools` module has a few neat built-ins that are faster for this. Look at the docs; sorry, I don't have time to write out a full explanation right now so keeping it to a comment. (actually, it looks like you might be using `itertools` already... nvm) **edit** just see Prune's answer :P

Comment: How does `getPMI()` work - how do you calculate the PMI ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right, my bad - didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino yep, just noticed that you noticed :)

Comment: @Dawn17 Yes, your edit captures what I described in my answer.  The follow-up comments are also spot-on: what you've described is an inherently **O(N^2)** process.  There's no way we can predict what you'll have for time saving, because we don't know the details of your `combinations` generator, nor the computations involved.

Comment: Note that you cite a time of "about 30 minutes", but an input set whose size is merely "huge".  Without specifics, we can't help tune this.  Give us some actual data (or at least the size) and the computations you're doing; perhaps the computation could be made sub-linear with respect to the quantity of pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one immediate improvement is to make your iteration directly from the pairs generator (assuming that `combinations` is your private generator, bypassing the `itertools` optimized version)

```
for p in combinations(words, 2):
```

This will allow the run-time system to optimize the generate-and-fetch as best it can, and saves the overhead of saving the huge list in memory.

Comment: So, you mean just like my edit? But I dont actually get that that actually differs from storing that first and iterating through it. Would there be a big difference in the speed?

Comment: if the result of `combinations(words, 2)` is very big, creating a list with all the results and storing it will take additional overhead that you can prevent. That said - I wouldn't agree that it *must* have a tremendous effect without measuring it.

Comment: @Dawn17 fundamentally, if your algorithm requires you to check every possible pair, then iterating like above is the fastest way possible. But you will still be stuck with quadratic time complexity, and there's no escaping that as `len(words)` grows larger. So unless you can think of some way *not* to have to check every pair, there is no escaping your situation.